# Ethereum Truffle init project gives error after 'truffle migrate' command

Tags: nodejs, truffle

### Issue

I want to create a default generated project working with Truffle. After running the commands `truffle init`, `truffle compile` and `truffle migrate` I got the error: `Expected parameter 'from' not passed to function.` The geth rpc is successfully running in the other window of Terminal so it's not the cause of the problem. I expect Truffle to start deploying migrations for the default Truffle project.

### Actual Results

```
Using network 'development'.

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:23538
        throw new Error("Expected parameter '" + key + "' not passed to function.");
        ^

Error: Expected parameter 'from' not passed to function.
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:23538:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.options (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:23536:19)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:66868:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:88946:23
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:67033:9
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:66861:7
    at done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:155469:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:155526:11
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
```

### Environment

- Operating System: macOS Sierra
- Truffle version: 3.4.9
- Ethereum client: Geth 1.6.7
- node version: 8.3.0
- npm version: 5.3.0

Answer (score 2):

truffle needs to know from which address you want to send transactions.

Try to specify this in `truffle.js` config file:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      from: <your address here>
    }
  }
};
```

Be sure that this address is unlocked in `geth` before deploying.

Comment: Now it gives me an error: http://imgur.com/a/v93Jq It says that the address is invalid, but I already unlocked it

Comment: Make sure your address is surrounded by double quotes, e.g. `"0xf2983...."`